# WFS-T editing of PostGIS table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

I just tested what I thought to be a very basic `PostgreSQL -> GeoServer WFS-t -> QGIS` setup that strangely issues an error.

I have a server on which I installed a PostgreSQL+PostGIS instance (featuring a point table) and a GeoServer instance. I set GeoServer to serve the postgis table as WFS-t, but requiring login to view and edit. Using the wfs link of GeoServer (`http://XXX/geoserver/wfs`) I loaded the layer in QGIS. Doing so without any login info, I can't see the layer as expected. **When I load the WFS layer in QGIS with the correct login info, I'm able to view it, but when I want to save edit's I get the following error in QGIS:**

`ERROR: Could not commit changes to layer`

I first thought I made an error in the permissions, but after checking all seems to be correct there. 
Anyone has experience with WFS-t in GeoServer? I'm note quite sure where the error could be. Some things I came accross:

- Some other errors related to OpenLayers+WFS editting pointed to 'Cross Origin Requests' and suggested to enable 'Cross-Origin Resource Sharing'.
- I heard that the default settings for WFS have changed in newer versions of GeoServer. Does that relate to more things than just the default setting of the WFS service level?
- Am I missing anything regarding the role settings? Does it suffice for WFS-t editing to give write access of that layer to a role?

Otherwise: does anyone know of a public WFS-t service I could use for testing if the error is not with QGIS?

---

Full layout of the GeoServer setup:
I'm using `GeoServer 2.10.0` on a Windows 2012 server. I followed [these steps](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/sysadmin/security/multiuser/index.html) to set up users and permissions and [these](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/sysadmin/wfst/index.html) to enable WFS-t. The result is:

- **stores**:

  - one store, connected to postgis on localhost
- **workspaces**:

  - workspace_private
- **roles** (under the default 'role service'):

  - role_private_view
  - role_private_edit
- **users** (under the default 'user group service')

  - user_private_view, connected to: role_private_view
  - user_private_edit, connected to: role_private_edit. **This is the user I use to login to the WFS.**
- **Permissions**:

  - Restrict viewing of private layers: read access in private workspace to 
    role_private_view + role_private_edit
  - Allow editing of the private layers: write access in private workspace to role_private_edit
  - Allow read-write access to vector data through transactions
    Services by setting WFS service level to 'Transactional'

The roles thus look like this:
[image: Roles]

The GeoServer log says (replaced url by `XXX` and layer by `YYY`):

```
2016-12-16 00:34:01,225 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2016-12-16 00:34:01,267 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2016-12-16 00:34:01,282 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Could not find type: {http://XXX/geoserver/workspace_private}YYY
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DescribeFeatureType.run(DescribeFeatureType.java:163)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.describeFeatureType(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
...
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-12-16 00:34:01,374 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.xml.impl.SchemaIndexImpl.buildElementIndex(SchemaIndexImpl.java:382)
    at org.geotools.xml.impl.SchemaIndexImpl.getElementIndex(SchemaIndexImpl.java:320)
    at org.geotools.xml.impl.SchemaIndexImpl.getElementDeclaration(SchemaIndexImpl.java:130)
    at org.geotools.xml.impl.HandlerFactoryImpl.createElementHandler(HandlerFactoryImpl.java:39)
    at org.geotools.xml.impl.DocumentHandlerImpl.createChildHandler(DocumentHandlerImpl.java:76)
    at org.geotools.xml.impl.ParserHandler.startElement(ParserHandler.java:562)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
...
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: There are known bugs/issues in recent QGIS (2.16 and newer) when it comes to WFS-T. GeoServer 2.10.1 will have some workarounds for the faulty requests that QGIS is building. 
I'm however not sure they are a match to your case though. You can have a look here:
https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7888 and https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7895

Comment: Ah, I've also found out that when editing the WFS connection, the "authentication" tab for "simple auth" is not effective, one has to go in the "configuration" tab and add a basic authentication configuration. Unsure what the authors mean by "simple authentication", http basic auth is as simple as it gets...

Comment: Thanks for the fast response @AndreaAime! Sadly, an alternate authentication via the "configuration" tab did not make it work and running the current snapshot build also didn't fix it :(

Comment: I believe stackexchange has become unsuitable for this kind of question then, it's more of a debugging problem than a straigth question/answer type. I'd ask on the geoserver-users mailing list instead, ideally you could prepare a self contained example using the data dir geoserver is shipping with (it's small, easy to transfer to a developer and easier to discuss because everybody can get it and reproduce)